# PDO foreach isn't displaying data being fetched

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So here I have a blog system.

My problem is that when I try to pull out data from the database, it is not displaying. Here is my current code, thanks!

index.php

```
<h1>News Blog</h1>
<form action="blog.php" method="POST">
    username: <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="name"><br />
    <textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post' />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['body'])){
    require'core/connect.php';

    $query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT name, body FROM blog WHERE name =:name AND body = :body");
    $query->bindParam(1, $_POST['name']);
    $query->bindParam(2, $_POST['body']);

    foreach($query-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
        echo $row['name'], '<br/><hr>';
        echo $row['body'];
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my blog.php if its necessary

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['body'])){
        require'core/connect.php';

        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO blog (name, body) VALUES (?,?)");
        $query->bindParam(1, $_POST['name']);
        $query->bindParam(2, $_POST['body']);

        if($query->execute()){
            echo 'Thank you for posting! Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to go back.';
        } else{
            echo 'There has been an error';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute your statement before fetch, and for a list page, you don't have to add the `where` part in your sql. There is no data post to the `index.php`.

Just change to below:

```
<?php
    require'core/connect.php';

    $query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT name, body FROM blog");
    $query->execute();

    foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
        echo $row['name'], '<br/><hr>';
        echo $row['body'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've already added the execute  line below, if($query->execute()){ some reason the data isn't being fetched.

Comment: have you printed the query and tried to run directly in phpmyadmin

Comment: @user3117992 Add your exactly code or it will be miss leading.

Comment: @user3117992 But you have problem in `index.php`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, it's not displaying the code i'm calling out from the database @xdazz

Comment: @user3117992 See my edit. There are no post data to your `index.php`.

Comment: @xdazz thanks! it's working now, so i didn't need to bind my Param in this case?

Comment: @xdazz one last thing, it is now inserting the data TWICE into my database, how can i prevent that?

Comment: @user3117992 `select name from blog where name = :name` ? Use the name to get the name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your [parameter binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) first. You are using `named placeholders` in your query but using `1-indexed` parameters in your `bindParam` calls.  Then you also need to execute the query:

```
$query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT name, body FROM blog WHERE name =:name AND body = :body");
$query->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
$query->bindParam(':body', $_POST['body']);

$query->execute(); 

foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
    echo $row['name'], '<br/><hr>';
    echo $row['body'];
}
```

Comment: I've tired this method, still not outputting the data that i inserted :(

Comment: @user3117992, the query is fine as long as you have data in your table for `name` and `body`.  Try removing the `space` after `$query->` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Still not displaying the data from the database that I've inserted even after removing the space. I can't seem to see what's wrong :(